# Android: Open application within control of another application

Tags: android

The idea is to launch an application, for example *Angry Birds*, from within my application.

However the catch is that my application must remain in control, so that when the user is done with the game he can return to what he was doing in my app.

Due to requirements this must be achieved without using the back button, home button or any other hardware buttons.

I know it's a long shot but I have to try.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your own custom launcher application analog to the home app.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html